# Video Editing: I'm unable to trim speed control strip's duration

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

I'm using the Video Editing mode, and trying to apply a speed control effect between two markers; For that purpose, I've managed to change the strip's 'trim duration (soft)' properties through setting the start value as the first marker time value, and the end value as the second one -- Yet, unfortunately, these values doesn't change, whenever I try, and gets always reset to 0.

Why I'm getting such behavior?

Comment: A screen shot of your problem would help. But you must apply a speed effect to the clip that you want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the clip at the points that you want to stretch, then select this strip. Press shift A key and add an Effect>Speed Effect. Then stretch the strip to your desired length.